# How to view another website within a Tab

Tags: extjs, extjs4

```
var tabs = Ext.widget('tabpanel', {
        renderTo: 'tabs',
        resizeTabs: true,
        enableTabScroll: true,
        width: 600,
        height: 250,
        defaults: {
            autoScroll: true,
            bodyPadding: 10
        },
        items: [{
            title: 'Tab 1003',
            iconCls: 'tabs',
            href:'http://www.yahoo.com',
            //hrefTarget:'_self',
            //html: 'Tab Body<br/><br/>' + Ext.example.bogusMarkup,
            closable: true
        }],

        .....
```

i have add a code  href:'http://www.yahoo.com' into items inside, but still can't work,
how to open www.yahoo.com page in the Tab Panel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a new panel to the tab-panel with an iframe in the html attribute.

Comment: but then you can't use a simple html link. You have to use a `button` which creats the new iframe-tab on a click

Comment: can what?i just put the iframe link to a page, let me easier maintaince?